# Implementing Procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have received the following assignment:

1. Create a procedure `setAccount` with the parameters `@AccountNumber`, `@CompanyName`, `@BankName` in SQL Server
2. Check in the procedure if `AccountNumber`, `CompanyName` or `BankName` already exist. If one of them exists, the procedure should return number 0. If none of them exists the procedure should insert the data in the corresponding tables. Please note the role of the table `Object`

An additional important information is that a `Counterparty` can be both a `Bank` and a `Company`.

The database (`.bak` file) can be downloaded using this [LINK](http://wikisend.com/download/145002/Test.bak).

The datamodel (generated with Mgmt Studio) is displayed here:

[image]

I noticed that (apart from the `Account` table) the tables are so defined that primary keys are not generated automatically. Please confirm this separately.

This is how I've done the procedure (RETURN commands are not returning 0 or 1 as output...):

```
ALTER PROC setAccount 
(
 @Kontonummer AS [varchar](255) = NULL
,@Firmenname AS [varchar](1000)
,@Bankname AS [varchar](255)
) 
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @FlagKontonummer AS SMALLINT
    DECLARE @FlagFirmenname AS SMALLINT
    DECLARE @FlagBankname AS SMALLINT

    SET @FlagKontonummer = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                            FROM [dbo].[Bank] 
                            WHERE Bankname LIKE '%' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@Kontonummer)) + '%')
    SET @FlagFirmenname = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                           FROM [dbo].[Bank] 
                           WHERE Bankname LIKE '%' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@Firmenname)) + '%')
    SET @FlagBankname = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                         FROM [dbo].[Bank] 
                         WHERE Bankname LIKE '%' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@Bankname)) + '%')


    IF @FlagKontonummer > 0 OR @FlagFirmenname > 0 OR @FlagBankname > 0 
        RETURN 0

    IF (@FlagKontonummer = 0 AND @FlagFirmenname = 0 AND @FlagBankname = 0)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @max_ob_ID AS INT
        DECLARE @p_company_id AS VARCHAR (MAX)

        SELECT @max_ob_ID = MAX(ObjectID) FROM [dbo].[Object]

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Object] ([ObjectID]) VALUES (@max_ob_ID + 1)

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Bank] (BankID, Bankname) 
        VALUES (@max_ob_ID + 1, LTRIM(RTRIM(@Bankname)))

        SELECT @max_ob_ID = MAX(ObjectID) FROM [dbo].[Object]

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Object] ([ObjectID]) VALUES (@max_ob_ID + 1)

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Company] (CompanyID, Companyname) 
        VALUES (@max_ob_ID + 1, LTRIM(RTRIM(@Firmenname)) )

        SELECT @p_company_id = CompanyID 
        FROM [dbo].[Company] 
        WHERE Companyname = LTRIM(RTRIM(@Firmenname))

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Account] ([AccountNumber], [CompanyID], [CounterpartyID]) 
        VALUES (@Kontonummer, @p_company_id, 10  -- ??? **COUNTERPARTY** - which one ??? ---
        )

        RETURN 1
    END
END
```

The MAIN QUESTION is: based on the given information is it possible to determine the correct `Counterparty`? From my point of view this information is missing, and in order to complete the task an additional information has to be provided.

Is that correct, or am I missing something?

Secondary question is regarding the procedure itself - would you write it in this matter, or is there a more elegant solution than mine?

Comment: What is a Counterparty?  This question smacks of a homework assignment.  Narrow down the scope a bit.

Comment: it is something like a homework assignment... But I do not think I got all the information. The one i am missing is the one about Counterparty. All information I got are written above. Counterpart is a foreign key in the Account table. From Account table it goes to Object table, and from there it can be joined either with Bank or Company table. That is why they said that Counterparty can be both - a bank and a company.
Problem is with INSERTing AccoungNr, Bank, Company in the procedure. When I insert AccountNt, nothing says what Counterparty should be, and Counterparty is defined as NOT NULL.

Comment: I is not excluded that an assignment has a trick, so you need to ask for additional information. However, I need another opinion.Am I missing something? I can insert a new Bank and a new Company, but when it comes with Account table, I have AccountNr and Foreign KEY for COmpany, but the main question remains - what can I do with Counterparty, since it can be both a company and a bank. Nowere in the assignment is this stated. Tthey just write two times "Please note that Counterparty can be both a company and a bank"

Comment: Until you describe the rules for deriving the counterparty we don't know. You can rewrite your SP. I would use `IF EXISTS` rather than `COUNT(*)` as count counts everything where exists stops at the first one. Also don't ever use `MAX` to work out your next ID. Always use IDENTITY to automatically assign one. When you use `MAX` and this thing gets called simultaneously you end up with the same ID and it throws an error when you try and insert (or worse affects integrity). In your diagram what is the purpose of the `object` table - if it's a linking table you need more than one column in it

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: thanks for the reply. Please understand that this is an assignment. With that said, my only goal is to write the procedure. Since this is an assignment, and not a real-life project, I am not allowed to change the data model (for example to define IDENTITY column on object table). The primary concern that I have now is - are all the information available to complete the assignment. In my personal opinion that is not the case, since the logic for inserting Counterparty is not provided. What is your opinion?

Comment: Additionally, I see the danger of using MAX function to determine the highest ID in the Object table. Given the provided information, and taking into account I am not allowed to change the data model (defining IDENTITY column) but only to write the procedure, how can I resolve the problem with determining the highest  ID without using MAX function?

Comment: Without using IDENTITY or things like sequences you can't. It's a shame that assignments encourage fundamentally bad practices. With regards to 'counterparty' you should probably find out what it is on wikipedia and understand it. Then you should make certain that the table `Object` really has that definition. I believe this table should have more columns and assist you to work out the counterparty.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: so if I understood you correctly, the way the assignment is posted, I have to use the MAX function to determine the correct ID. Regarding the counterparty, have you taken a look at the values in the tables? The Counterparty is located in the Account table. Beside Counterparty column the table contains Account_ID, AccountNumber and CompanyID columns. So one row looks sth like this (12, 1122334455, 25, 19). 25 is Company_ID (FK) and 19 is Cunterparty (FK). Counterparty FK connects with Object tbl. Object table contains ID values from both Bank and Company tables.

Comment: I haven't downloaded it, no - it would be easier if you did a sqlfiddle for everyone to play with. If Account is unique in that table, and account is passed in (as you indicate in the original question) then you can uniquely look up a counterparty with it. But I still don't understand where counterparty fits it - its not part of the original question

Comment: ... That is why Counterparty in the Acount table can hold and ID either from a company or from a bank. From here, and taking into consideration how the assignment was set, there is from my perspective no logic to determine what comes in Counterparty. For Bank, Company, and Account is clear - generate a new ID and add the new row. However the Counterparty has to reference either a bank or a  company, and with the provided information, I can't see which one it should reference...For example, a procedure is called with params (1122334455, 'company C', 'bank B'). What comes in Counterparty column?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: regarding your answer above: "If Account is unique in that table, and account is passed in (as you indicate in the original question) then you can uniquely look up a counterparty with it.". In the assignment says the following: "Check in the procedure if AccountNumber, CompanyName or BankName already exist. If one of them exists, the procedure should return number 0. If none of them exists the procedure should insert the data in the corresponding tables.". So the INSERT only happens if none of the parameters (AccountNr, Bankname, CompanyName) exist. -> Can't look Cntparty up..

Comment: My take on that is if the _record_ doesn't exist. That is a classic _CRUD_ stored procedure. Pass ins some parameters and 'make the record happen'. In fact your existing SP code does that - checks if the records exist